# Nuxt Fatal Error - Cannot find module '@/helper/consts.js' in '..\routes\index.js'

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

Why, I cannot import this file: `import {POPULAR} from "@/helper/consts.js";`
into: /routes/index.js in NUXT.

I want a consts variable for paths, but compiler after `npm run dev` throw error...

[image]

here is `routes/index.js` something like that:
[image]

what if I would like import any i18n key?

folders structure:
[image]

`helper/consts.js`:
[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please show more of your file and rule structure?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. Take a look at my edited post.

Comment: Was talking more about the other one actually.

Comment: ops, sory. But what is 'rule structure'? Do you mean structure folders?

Comment: whats inside consts.js ?

Comment: does this exists "@/helper/consts.js'

Comment: inside consts.js are const strings. I Updated my post, please look guys.